# Preloading <picture> element loads two images

Tags: html, image, google-chrome, preload

I have a `<picture>` element with multiple sources for multiple device widths and trying to assemble a correct `<link rel="preload">` element to preload a single image that fits the media query defined for the `<picture>`.  For some reason, my code results in browser loading two images when looking at Chrome devtool's Network tab.

What am I misunderstanding here?

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" imagesrcset="/big.webp 885w, /mobile.webp 420w, /fallback.jpg 885w" imagesizes="(min-width: 421px) 885px, (max-width: 420px) 420px">

<picture>
    <source srcset="/big.webp" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 421px)">
    <source srcset="/mobile.webp" type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 420px)">
    <img src="/fallback.jpg" fetchpriority="high" width="885" height="570" class="img-fluid" alt="example">
</picture>
```

The two images that are loaded are

`/big.webp` and `/mobile.webp`

```html
<link rel="preload" as="image" imagesrcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800 885w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800/ff0000 420w, https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800/00ff00 885w" imagesizes="(min-width: 421px) 885px, (max-width: 420px) 420px">

<picture>
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800" type="image/webp" media="(min-width: 421px)">
  <source srcset="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800/ff0000" type="image/webp" media="(max-width: 420px)">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1200x800/00ff00" fetchpriority="high" width="885" height="570" class="img-fluid" alt="example">
</picture>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was only able to find a partial solution by setting two separate `<link rel="preload">` elements with respective `media` attributes like so:

```
<link rel="preload" as="image" imagesrcset="/big.webp"
imagesizes="885px" media="(min-width: 421px)">


<link rel="preload" as="image" imagesrcset="mobile.webp"
imagesizes="420px" media="(max-width: 420px)">
```

This way, only one of these images gets downloaded. The only issue is with the `fallback.jpg` image since it has the same size rule as the `big.webp` therefore cannot be defined like the others above (both images with the same size would get downloaded). I have to settle for this solution for the time being, unless someone comes up with a way to include all three images in the preload.